# How to Inject Interface as a parameter to function using flask-injector

Tags: python-3.x, flask, dependency-injection, flask-restful

I am working on an API app using flask-injector and connexion. I have following setups -

The Interface -

```
class RestaurantsProvider(Module):
@inject
def __init__(self, items: list=[]):
    self._items = items

@provider
def get(self, number_of_items: int=5) -> list:
    if not self._items:
        return []

    if number_of_items > len(self._items):
        number_of_items = len(self._items)

    return self._items
```

The binding -

```
from connexion.resolver import RestyResolver
import connexion
from injector import Binder, CallableProvider
from flask_injector import FlaskInjector
from services.provider import RestaurantsProvider

def configure(binder: Binder) -> Binder:
    binder.bind(
        interface=RestaurantsProvider.RestaurantsProvider,
        to=  RestaurantsProvider.RestaurantsProvider([{"Name":"Fgh"}])
    );


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = connexion.App(__name__, port=2508, 
           specification_dir='swagger/')
   app.add_api('restaurants.yaml', resolver=RestyResolver('api'))
   # app.run(ssl_context=('cert.pem','key.pem'))
   FlaskInjector(app=app.app, modules=[configure])
   app.run()
```

And Now I want to inject this interface in a function like this

```
@inject(data_provider = RestaurantsProvider)
def search(data_provider) -> list:
    return data_provider.get()
```

But the newer version of injector (0.13.0) doesn't allow parameterized injection and I went through the documentation and couldn't figure out how to inject the interface to this function.

Note - This function is in api.restaurants.py and is getting called as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just use @inject and then:

```
search(data_provider: RestaurantsProvider)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Once it's out there, I feel a lot stupid to not be able to figure this out myself.